# I want to create an instance of this class which has arguments in its constructor as follows?

Tags: constructor, arguments, nestjs, passport-local

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: PassportLocalModel<IUser>,
  ) {}

  async register(user: CreateUserDto) {
    let status: RegistrationStatus = {
      success: true,
      message: 'user registerd',
    };
    await this.userModel.register(
      new this.userModel({
        username: user.email,
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
      }),
      user.password,
      err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          status = { success: false, message: err };
        }
      },
    );
    return status;
  }


}
```

I want to create an instance of this class but I am not able to figure out how to pass the arguments. How to handle the arguments for passport local model containing Iuser?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you lack on comprehension of the Dependency Injection of NestJS.

You should never instantiate a Service, but import it in the constructor of other class in the same way you are doing it with the `UsersService`.

For example, having your `AuthService`annotated with `@Service` decorator:

```
@Service
export class AuthService { ... }
```

You can then use it, let's say, in your `AuthController`

```
@Controller()
export class AuthController{
  constructor (private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  register(user: UserDTO): RegistrationStatus {
    this.authService.register(user);
  }
}
```

NestJS will handle the instantiation of the Service and all its dependencies.
Just remember to add the `AuthService` in the `providers` property of the `AuthModule`, and, if you are going to use outside this module, export it adding it to the `exports` property.

Is a good practice to specify return types in methods.